# How to optimize the SQL query and add more array elements to the existing array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, associative-array

I've an array named `$insert_users` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d
    [1] => a6d22e4cc3f65778a60b359842bcec82
    [2] => e17151c98358b60910d4d9fd6ae73ac4
    [3] => 472d3d7eca74cb3518bcba787aee8540
)
```

Now I have to fire an SQL query for each of these ids from the above array. The code I've written for this is as follows:

```
foreach($insert_users as $key => $value ) {


$sql  = " SELECT DISTINCT ud.user_mobile_number, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name FROM OCN.users_groups_subscribe ugs JOIN OCN.users_details ud ON ud.user_id=ugs.subscribe_user_id JOIN OCN.users u ON u.user_id=ugs.subscribe_user_id WHERE ugs.subscribe_user_id ='".$value."'";

            $this->mDb->Query( $sql);
            $students_data = $this->mDb->FetchArray();                          
            }
```

It returns me following array for single id element from the `$insert_users` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_mobile_number] => 9929933345
            [user_first_name] => Ashish
            [user_last_name] => Patil
        )

)
```

But I'm not getting the array in desired format. I want the array `$students_data` in following format and for all the values from the array `$insert_users`:

```
Array(  
     [0]=>Array
     (
        [user_full_name] => Ashish Patil //This key should be newly generated & should contain values of keys user_first_name & user_last_name concatenated to each other
        [user_mobile_number] => 9929933345
     )
)
```

Also, can anyone tell me is there any way to fire the SQL query just once and get the desired array which will contain details for all the ids from array `$insert_users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing

```
foreach($insert_users as $key => $value ) {


    $sql  = " SELECT DISTINCT ud.user_mobile_number, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name FROM OCN.users_groups_subscribe ugs JOIN OCN.users_details ud ON ud.user_id=ugs.subscribe_user_id JOIN OCN.users u ON u.user_id=ugs.subscribe_user_id WHERE ugs.subscribe_user_id ='".$value."'";

    $this->mDb->Query( $sql);
    $students_data = $this->mDb->FetchArray();                          
}
```

Do

```
$value = "'" . implode("','", $insert_users) . "'";
$sql  = " SELECT DISTINCT ud.user_mobile_number, CONCAT(u.user_first_name,' ',u.user_last_name) AS user_full_name FROM OCN.users_groups_subscribe ugs JOIN OCN.users_details ud ON ud.user_id=ugs.subscribe_user_id JOIN OCN.users u ON u.user_id=ugs.subscribe_user_id WHERE ugs.subscribe_user_id IN(" .$value . ")";

$this->mDb->Query( $sql);
$students_data = $this->mDb->FetchArray();
```

Now you should get all the result you want in one query

Answer (score 1):

Won't this help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ud.user_mobile_number,
CONCAT(u.user_first_name,' ',u.user_last_name) AS user_full_name 
FROM OCN.users_groups_subscribe ugs
JOIN OCN.users_details ud ON ud.user_id=ugs.subscribe_user_id
JOIN OCN.users u ON u.user_id=ugs.subscribe_user_id
WHERE ugs.subscribe_user_id ='".$value."'";
```

Comment: Yes it works to concat the two strings but there should be a space between first name and last name. How should it get insert?

Comment: See now..the space will be inserted.

Comment: Also it's only about the concatenation part. What about the single query to get the desired array? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean here by single query? Is this not one single query?

Comment: Yes, this is a single query. But it gets fired for every foreach iteration. I want to reduce that. Is there any way to reduce that? Got my point?